# how to maintain scroll bar position in android listview?

Tags: android, listview

Friends,

I am displaying an array in ListView.

I change data of array dynamically on button click and call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

It does not maintain scroll bar position of list. (the lenght of data source to list is always same). 
Could any one guide me how to keep the last state of ListView ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Get the top position from the first visible element
int idx = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View vfirst = list.getChildAt(0);
int pos = 0;
if (vfirst != null) pos = vfirst.getTop();

//Restore the position
list.setSelectionFromTop(idx, pos);
```

Comment: please correct code or it is not understandable what is v here?  is it like if(vfirst != null)

Comment: tiny error in the code:

`v.getTop()` should be `vfirst.getTop()`

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to refresh some changes in data, use

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Instead. And scroll will be in the same position.